# How much entropy is needed for encrypting data locally?

Tags: password-cracking, entropy

I understand that, when storing data on the cloud or something else that might get leaked to the public, the security margin should be at least 128 bit, 256 bit should be used for data that should stay secure over 20-30 years.

If I use a storage mechanism (like WebStorageAPI) to store data of my application on the client, is it secure enough to use a key derived from the password of the user (about 40 bit entropy) to encrypt the data locally if a random person of the public got access to the unlocked device (like in university or in a café)?

The idea is, that the device could then generate a key that is used to encrypt the data that is stored online and encrypt it locally using the password of the user. This way the security of the data that is stored online does not depend on the strength of the password, only attacks with access to the device would be possible.
(It would be necessary to communicate that key between devices in a multi-device-setting, but let's assume that this issue is already solved)

Comment: WebStorage? That's JavaScript. Are you certain you understand how to secure it? The moment you link authentication to JavaScript, it is functionally insecure. I can trivially add hooks to the code and capture  your encryption/decryption tokens.

Comment: @Nelson, I'm starting with javascript for the beginning, yes.
I am not sure if I understand what you are saying, but if I understand it correctly could say the same about everything that is done cryptographically online, right? You could use that same argument to state that web.whatsapp.com, protonmail.com, sync.com and all the password managers are insecure, right?

Comment: No, because the content isn't stored in an easily accessible location, nor is the access to the token and security pathways trivially easy. You can secure a local application better than JavaScript in the browser. Yes, you can technically reverse engineer it, you can analyze data packets, but this all takes extra work, and there are protocols to protect all that. There isn't anything really to secure WebStorage in the manner that you want to use it for; the storage of encrypted data. WebStorage is basically just enhanced cookies.

Comment: @Nelson I don't see how the access to the key is trivially easy when encrypted with eg. PBKDF2(password), would you mind explaining it to me? i don't quite understand what you mean

Comment: The issue is how is it encrypted? Are you using JavaScript to encrypt it? I can pull your key out of the code. If the WebStorage is primarily only just a stream of data and you do no encryption on the client machine, then it is fine, but the moment you try to encrypt using JavaScript, it's pointless since I can intercept the code before the encryption is done. That's what I mean by understanding how to secure it. I can literally put in code breakpoints on live code to stop whatever you are doing and read all the variables, and there's nothing you can do to stop me.

Comment: The key point is this. Whatever JavaScript you are running, expect a malicious actor to completely prevent/interrupt whatever it is doing. If it is not encrypted before being processed by JavaScript, it isn't secure period. You mentioned "encrypt it locally". If you do this with JavaScript, I can stop that from happening. You can't rely on JavaScript from executing.

Comment: Oh, I think you don't understand what I mean. The key and the data are already known to the user. The only reason I want to do this encryption is because the server should not be able to see the user data. Does that make more sense? There is no reason for the user to disable the encryption.

Comment: You can do it as an experiment, but relying on JavaScript to encrypt sensitive data is a recipe for disaster. You absolutely cannot assume JavaScript to be functional, so your security model should compensate for that. I worked on a production financial system where the date field was authenticated by JS, and once in a while a credit card transaction with a blank date comes in. I had to rewrite it to perform server side authentication to prevent dateless transactions. Do not rely on JavaScript for critical data.

Comment: Well, I can't encrypt it on the server side because the server should not know the user key, is there any way I can make this work? I think there is nothing beside Javascript to execute in a browser, how are password managers like LastPass doing this? They have to use javascript as well to encrypt the passwords on the client, do they not?

Comment: @Nelson: Yes, of course the user could disable the encryption process, but why would he do that? The only purpose of the encryption is to secure the data of the user, why would he disable it?

Comment: I can also ask why a user would disable JavaScript on their payment to an electric company, causing his power to be cut, but there's no way I can figure it out unless I ask the customer of my B2B client to send in their computer. I'm simply saying assuming JavaScript to always be working, for encryption, is just going to blow up in your face eventually. If it's not outright data leak, then you'll have random data corruption because it'll try to decrypt already decrypted data. I'm offering serious advice on using JavaScript for encryption. Try it out and you'll learn them the hard way.

Comment: The nature of JavaScript is "best effort". Failures are silent. Webpages keep going, and there're ways to just ignore JS errors and plow through. The entire stack isn't secure, and you're trying to perform encryption on it. It's up to you to continue, and for the sake of learning it is good, but you will never get security compliance on the system, and anyone with web development experience and some basic understanding of security will immediately consider the system insecure. I'm giving you honest opinion on how viable JS is for encryption. Bottom line, it's not.

Comment: @Nelson Thank you very much for the input. I think this will be a risk I have to accept. If the user turns off JavaScript, no data will be stored anyway since everything shall be done via the fetch api. If a user specifically removes the encryption or decryption part then this is his own responsibility. Now, going away from JavaScript: I think my question boils down to what an appropriate device password is. This question is opinion-based and so I think the question can be closed anyway